# How do you model case classes to reflect database queries results in a reusable manner

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

I will go with an example.

Say I have three tables defined like this:

(pseudocode)

```
Realm
  id: number, pk
  name: text, not null

Family
  id: number, pk
  realm_id: number, fk to Realm, pk
  name: text, not null

Species
  id: number, pk
  realm_id: number, fk to Family (and therefore to Realm), pk,
  family_id: number, fk to Family, pk,
  name: text, not null
```

A temptative case classes definition would be

```scala
case class Realm (
  id: Int,
  name: String
)

case class Family (
  id: Int,
  realm: Realm,
  name: String
)

case class Species (
  id: Int,
  family: Family,
  name: String
)
```

If I make a json out of this after querying the database it would look like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM realm
  JOIN family
    ON family.realm_id = realm.id
  JOIN species 
    ON species.family_id = family.id
    AND species.realm_id = family.realm_id
```

Example data:

```
  [{
    "id": 1,
    "family": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Mammal",
      "realm": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Animal"
      }
    },
    "name": "Human"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "family": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Mammal",
      "realm": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Animal"
      }
    },
    "name": "Cat"
  }]
```

Ok, so far... This is usable, if I need to show every species grouped by realm, I would transform the JsValue or in javascript do filters, etc. However when posting data back to the server, these classes seem a little awkward. If I want to add a new species I would have to post something like this:

```
  {
    "id": ???,
    "family": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Mammal", // Awkward
      "realm": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Animal" // Awkward
      }
    },
    "name": "Cat"
  }
```

Should my classes be then:

```scala
case class Realm (
  id: Int,
  name: Option[String]
)

case class Family (
  id: Int,
  realm: Realm,
  name: Option[String]
)

case class Species (
  id: Option[Int],
  family: Family,
  name: String
)
```

Like this, I can omit posting what it seems to be unnecesary data, but then the classes definition don't reflect what is in the database which are not nullable fields.

Queries are projection of data. More or like `Table.map(function) => Table2`. When data is extracted from the database and I don't get the name field, it doesn't mean it is null. How do you deal with this things?

Comment: None != null, whats the problem sorry?

Comment: @samthebest Can you elaborate a little on your comment? None != null but they both mean to represent optional fields on what they represent in their context. Null for the database is the same as Option in scala, no?; they behave differently. The expression `null == null`, is true in scala and false in the database.

Comment: No, `None` does not mean `null`, you should not interchange them to mean the same thing. After all an `Option` can actually be null, but this does not mean its `None`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with it is to represent the interconnection using other data structures instead of letting each level know about the next.

For example, in the places where you need to represent the entire tree, you could represent it with:

```
Map[Realm, Map[Family, Seq[Species]]]
```

And then just `Realm` in some places for example as a REST/JSON resource, and maybe `(Species, Family, Realm)` in some place where you only want to work with one species but need to know about the other two levels in the hierarchy.

I would also advice you to think two or three times about letting your model structure define your JSON structure, what happens with the codes that consumes your JSON when you change *anything* in your model classes? (And if you really want that, do you actually need to go via a model structure, why not build your JSON directly from the database results and skip one level of data transformation?)